# Clojureでリストからマップを作るには

Tags: clojure

キーと値のリストからマップを作りたいです。

```
((:a 1) (:b 2))
```

このリストをマップにしたい。

```
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

以下のようにして結果は得られたのですが、もっとこう簡単に、またClojureらしい方法があるのではないかと思いました。

```
(apply merge (map #(apply assoc {} %) '((:a 1) (:b 2))))
```

よりよい方法があれば教えてください。

よりよいと考える理由も教えてください。

僕の方法がよくないのではないかと考える理由は効率です。リストの要素ごとにキーひとつだけのマップをまず作り、それからひとつのマップにまとめています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(into {} (for [[k v] '((:a 1) (:b 2))][k v]))`

とか？

Comment: 元のリストの形が `([:a 1] [:b 2])`のようにもっと都合よく作られていれば、`(into {} '([:a 1] [:b 2]))`と、とても簡潔に書けますね! 思いつきませんでした。

Comment: そうです`for`はその変換をします。

Answer (score 0):

最初から元の連想リストをリストではなくベクタを要素にして作っておくのがいいんじゃないでしょうか。直接intoで扱えますから

```
(into {} '([:a 1] [:b 2]))
```

連想リストはClojureではあまり使わない気がします。

質問にあるコードはreduceを使えば改善できます(intoも中身はreduceです)

```
(reduce #(apply assoc %1 %2) {} '((:a 1) (:b 2)))
```

Comment: はい。元の連想リストじたいも自分で作った関数の出力なので、ベクタのリストを返したほうがClojureでは便利のようだとわかりました。